# Does having the same background for all the images of a particular class increase a CNN model's ability to classify the images?

Tags: conv-neural-network, multi-class

I'm working on a multi-class skin disease classification problem.

The input images are skin diseased images that have varying backgrounds.

Does maintaining the same background (maybe a white/black background) for all the images help while training a CNN model? If so, what techniques should I use to generate the same background, so that the focus is only on the skin?

Comment: If you have a white background for the healthy skin and a red background for the diseased skin, your model might just start classifying white backgrounds vs red backgrounds and ignore what the disease looks like. Is that along the lines of what you mean?

Comment: @Dave.  My dataset has 5 classes. (4 types of skin disease and one class of healthy skin). I was thinking of maintaining a black (or white) background for all the images irrespective of the class of the image. Also, I thought if I have maintained a specific background while training the model then I must convert the background of a new image accordingly while testing the model.

Answer (score 1):

If you transform your images to all have the same background, you are removing noise from your data. This means a model trained on these transformed images may be more accurate on other images *transformed in the same way*. You would need to transform your test images as well - and include this transformation in the ML pipeline, if you intend to use this model in an application. If you don't, the model is likely to get confused by the background and would probably perform worse than a model trained on the original images would perform.

If you want to try this, you could use object detection techniques (for an into to these, see [Jason Brownlee's "A Gentle Introduction to Object Recognition With Deep Learning"](https://machinelearningmastery.com/object-recognition-with-deep-learning/)) to detect the skin, then mask out the rest of the image.